# Image not loading in HTML

Tags: html, image

I was trying to load an image on my webpage using the "img src" tag, but then the image did not load. My path is correct, I tried to load the image from the body and head section of the code. It didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<img src = "C:/Users/galde/Desktop/Web Development/Projects/Personal Site/Images/icon.png" alt = "An image of Ghazi Aldeeb">
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: I would avoid spaces in folder and file names (for example replace them with an underscore, like "Web_development")

Comment: Ok, I'll try removing the spaces.

Comment: Hmm... I added underscores but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AlonEitan Do you mean the terminal?

Comment: You can't load images from local files this way in HTML. File URLs will work, but only on localhost. Otherwise, you need to get your webserver to host the image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try having a relative route not containing any spaces? for example assuming the line is already inside Personal Site in a different directory, try this:

```
<img src = "../Images/icon.png" alt = "An image of Ghazi Aldeeb">
```

If you are at the route of the project try this

```
<img src = "/Images/icon.png" alt = "An image of Ghazi Aldeeb">
```

Absolute routes are things you may want to avoid as well as spaces or special characters in directory names

Answer (score 0):

If your image is in the same folder as your html file you can try this

```
<img src="icon.png" alt = "An image of Ghazi Aldeeb">
```

Comment: You probably are doing something wrong. If the html file and image are in same directory this answer should work.